# Starting tomcat on google compute engine Linux vm

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have created a f1-micro instance in google compute engine vm and installed java and tomcat8 using the following command

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
sudo apt-get install tomcat8
```

Once tomcat is installed I can access it via curl http://localhost:8080 and by using the vm's external IP:8080. Also if I modify the default /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.index.html it reflects immediately.

But then if I just stop tomcat and start back again(without any other changes) it never starts. I don't see any error in `catalina.out` as well

Again if i check if tomcat is running or not by using `sudo netstat -lnp | grep 8080` I get one entry:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      8749/java
```

In the first run log I can see something like

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
.......
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT has finished in 1,574 ms
```

but after the restart I only see

```
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
```

there is no deployment success log

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww so you mean deployment of a developed web application is not part of developement?

Comment: As written, installing and configuring the VM or troubleshooting the failed start of the web server is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a deployment question, then maybe you should edit the question to reflect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main reason it took time to start is it was not finding enough randomness in the the entropy pool.

To fix this go to the `JDK/security` folder and edit java.security

in my case it was located at:  `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/security/java.security`

Change

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/random
```

to

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache Tomcat comes with a simple ROOT webapp that is nothing more than a precompiled index JSP page. This index page was precompiled into a JAR file.
By default root folder comes with index.jsp file instead of index.html.
If you changed it make sure update the web configuration file of tomcat to compile it from the jar file.

follow the procedure for updating the index.jsp file as:
The easiest way to change the contents of the index.jsp page is to remove this index_jsp servlet from the ROOT webapp. Once you remove the index_jsp servlet and restart Tomcat, Tomcat will see the index.jsp file in the ROOT directory and compile it on the fly into a class file. You now will be able to edit the ROOT/index.jsp file and have those changes take effect immediately by reloading the http://localhost:8080/ page.

To remove the index_jsp servlet, edit the ROOT web application's configuration file, $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/web.xml. Comment out the definition of the servlet and the servlet mapping, so that section of the file will look like this (changes in red):

```
<!-- JSPC servlet mappings start -->
<!-- Disabling the index_jsp servlet
<servlet>
<servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
-->
<!-- JSPC servlet mappings end -->
```